# Trying to drag ship on canvas from left to right in Space Invaders clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a "ship" that I have drawn on my canvas and I want to be able to drag it left and right on the bottom of the canvas when it is clicked. I have done some research but I'm having no luck.

I'm assuming I use onMouseDown to do this so I have this when the page loads...

```
canGame.onMouseDown = canCanvas.onMouseDown(e);
```

and here is the code that creates my ship

```
gShip = spriteNew("MediumSpringGreen", 230, 950, 150, 20);
```

From there I am not really sure what to do. I have a gameUpdate function which moves the invaders down the screen. A gameInit function that will draw the invaders and ship on the screen. Also I have a gameDraw function which draws everything on the screen. I have a few others which are not really important for my issue.

Here is the jsfiddle with the full source code. For some reason though it will run on my browser when I run the HTM file but not in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/f66bk/2/

Comment: Your code does not work in jsfiddle only because in the section "Frameworks & Extensions", you should select "No wrap - in <head>"

Comment: What have you tried so far? You will probably need 3 events: mousedown to know that the mouse is down to drag your ship; mousemove that will give you the position(x, y) of your mouse if your mouse is down so that you can redraw your ship; mouseup to know that you are not dragging your ship anymore.

Comment: I haven't tried any of that. I'll research those events and see what I can do

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in comment, the best way of doing this kind of behaviour is by using the events `mouseup`, `mousedown` and `mousemove`.

I defined a var named `isMouseDown` to know that the ship is dragged that I set to true on mousedown and false on mouseup:

```
canGame.onMouseDown = function() { isMouseDown = true }
canGame.onMouseUp = function() { isMouseDown = false }
```

You will also need the event onmousemove to get your mouse position to redraw your ship properly:

```
canGame.onMouseUp = function(event) { moveShip(event, this) }
```

In the function `moveShip`, you can get your mouse position and set the position of your ship properly:

```
function moveShip(evt, obj) {
    if(!isMouseDown)
        return;

    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement,
        rect = target.getBoundingClientRect(),
        offsetX = evt.clientX - rect.left;

    gShip.Rect.X = offsetX - gShip.Rect.Width/2;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/f66bk/5/) is your jsfiddle :)